why is it not printing 2.0? Why can't I see a message?
Why doesn't 2.0 work?
My expected output: 1.0 and 2.0
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    for(float i= 0.0; i<=3.0; i += 0.2){
        if(i == 1.0){
            printf("1.0\n");
        }
        if( i == 2.0){
            printf("2.0\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

enter image description here

What happens when you step through the code in the debugger and watch what happens, keeping a watch on the value of i? If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is the perfect time to learn. The code you've written is simple and short enough that you can single-step through every single line that can possibly execute in just a minute or two.

Value 0.2 does not exists. Instead it is converted to something like 0.200000000000000011. And adding this value 5 times to 1.0, you get a value that is a little bit larger than 2.0.
